# Can "stare" have the meaning of "andare"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I have read the following sentence in [Treccani](http://treccani.it/enciclopedia/focalizzazioni_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/):

> Appena uscito dalla palestra, sono stato in biblioteca.

I would initially translate it as "As soon as I left the gym, I was in the library", but that makes no sense unless the library and gym are adjacent rooms, which is unlikely. I guess that "stare" means "andare" in this context?  I have not found that meaning in https://www.wordreference.com/iten/stare. Is it usual?

Comment: It's essentially the difference between "I've gone to the library (and I'm still there)" and "I've been to the library (and then I left)"

Comment: @DenisNardin minor: If I'm still at the library, I think I'd say "I've come to the library" in English (and not "I've gone").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't simply translate to *andare*; the idea of going to the library is implicit, but the sentence conveys the sense of having gone to the library, staying there for a while. However, the speaker is no longer in the library.

How would you say this in English? I think you can use *to stay* as well:

> As soon as I left the gym, I stayed at the library for a while.

Of course, in order to stay at the library, you have to go there, but you don't need to say that explicitly.

The Italian sentence *could* also mean

> As soon as I left the gym, I went to the library.

if the context makes clear that I went there for a short time, for instance in order to return a book I borrowed. However, for this case, I'd use *Appena uscito dalla palestra, sono stato alla biblioteca*, that is, I didn't really stay there long. Alternatively, *sono passato dalla biblioteca*.

Comment: Do "stare in biblioteca" and "stare alla biblioteca" imply the duration of permanence?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista “sono stato alla biblioteca” (past) is good; “sto alla biblioteca” is regional.

Comment: ok, but I was asking about the implied duration of permanence in "*in* biblioteca" and "*alla* biblioteca". In your answer, you say that "sono stato in biblioteca" expresses that you stayed there for a while and "sono stato alla biblioteca" expresses that you didn't stay there long.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista It's “stare in” that conveys the idea of duration.

Comment: @greg I am confused now. I thought that the preposition used after "andare", "essere", "stare" depended only on the place, eg andare/essere/stare/ in biblioteca, andare/essere/stare al mare. Are you saying that the choice of the preposition after "andare" depends on the place and the preposition after "stare" depends on the duration of permanence ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista No, it's not that simple, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg: I think that the verb in the sentence "sono stato in biblioteca" is "essere" and not "stare" (presente: "sono in biblioteca" --> passato prossimo: "sono stato in biblioteca").

Comment: @Charo Both interpretations are possible.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your assumption can be considered correct; but in this case the meaning of the verb "stare" [can be this one, taken from Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare/):

> Essere, trovarsi, permanere in un dato luogo, o in una determinata condizione.
>
> To be, to stay, to linger in a given place, or in a given condition.

So the expression "sono stato in biblioteca" is used to say that yes, he went to the library, but it remarks that he passed some time there.

It is pretty used; for example you can say:

> Sono stato al mare = I've been at the seaside (I spent there some days).

or

> Sono stato dai miei parenti = I visited my relatives